# Site switcher reports a different number of sites on stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, stack-exchange-button, tooltips

Here on Meta, the site switcher tooltip reports **132** sites:

[image: meta]

But on http://stackexchange.com the number is **135**:

[image: se.com]

This does not look like  caching, since (as far as I know) SE did not launch or shut down three sites at once recently.

Comment: Not to mention [All sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid) only list 130 sites; +Area 51 +Stack Apps = 132; +3 private beta = 135? (ja.so, cs50.se, edx-cs169-1x.se)